# Como detectar se uma variável é nula?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, variáveis

Estou tentando validar um formulário simples em Python 3 e quero fazer com que ele não registre as informações caso o campo `nome` esteja vazio, porém quando faço um `if` para verificar se a variável `name` está vazia, ele me retorna que ela não é nula.

Segue o código:

```
import Imports
import Dados

import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

Imports.Connect_db()


class Gravar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Abre o clipboard
        self.clipboard = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)
        self.entry = Gtk.Entry()

        # Abre o xml
        builder = Gtk.Builder()
        builder.add_from_file("form.glade")

        # Pega a janela
        self.window = builder.get_object("window1")

        # Pega a area de texto
        self.text_name = builder.get_object("text_name")
        self.text_passwd = builder.get_object("text_passwd")
        self.text_numb = builder.get_object("text_numb")

        # abre a janela de dialogo
        self.about = builder.get_object("about_dialog")

        # Abre as janelas
        self.window.show()

        builder.connect_signals({"Gtk_main_quit": Gtk.main_quit,
                                 "on_submit_clicked": self.cadastro,
                                 "on_text_name_activate": self.cadastro,
                                 "on_text_passwd_activate": self.cadastro,
                                 "on_text_numb_activate": self.cadastro,
                                 "on_delete_activate": self.delete_text,
                                 "on_about_activate": self.about_window})

    def cadastro(self, widget):
        name = self.text_name.get_text()
        passwd = self.text_passwd.get_text()
        numb = self.text_numb.get_text()

        if name == None:
            print("Nula")
        else:
            print("n nula")

        Dados.commit(name, passwd, numb)

        Gravar.delete_text(self, widget)

    def delete_text(self, widget):
        self.text_name.set_text("")
        self.text_passwd.set_text("")
        self.text_numb.set_text("")

    def about_window(self, widget):
        self.about.run()

        self.about.hide()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    win = Gravar()

    Gtk.main()
```

Glade

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.18.3 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.12"/>
  <object class="GtkAboutDialog" id="about_dialog">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="resizable">False</property>
    <property name="modal">True</property>
    <property name="type_hint">dialog</property>
    <property name="skip_taskbar_hint">True</property>
    <property name="urgency_hint">True</property>
    <property name="gravity">center</property>
    <property name="program_name">Formulario</property>
    <property name="version">2.0</property>
    <property name="comments" translatable="yes">Formulario integrado com python3 e mysql</property>
    <property name="authors">Guilherme</property>
    <property name="artists">Guilherme</property>
    <property name="logo_icon_name">image-missing</property>
    <child internal-child="vbox">
      <object class="GtkBox" id="aboutdialog-vbox1">
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <property name="spacing">2</property>
        <child internal-child="action_area">
          <object class="GtkButtonBox" id="aboutdialog-action_area1">
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="layout_style">end</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">False</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Cadastro user</property>
    <property name="resizable">False</property>
    <property name="window_position">center</property>
    <property name="gravity">center</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="Gtk_main_quit" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkMenuBar" id="menubar1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem2">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">_Editar</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                <child type="submenu">
                  <object class="GtkMenu" id="menu2">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="delete">
                        <property name="label">gtk-delete</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                        <signal name="activate" handler="on_delete_activate" swapped="no"/>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem4">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Aj_uda</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                <child type="submenu">
                  <object class="GtkMenu" id="menu3">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="about">
                        <property name="label">gtk-about</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                        <signal name="activate" handler="on_about_activate" swapped="no"/>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkGrid" id="grid2">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="margin_top">36</property>
            <property name="row_spacing">14</property>
            <property name="column_homogeneous">True</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkEntry" id="text_name">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="margin_right">48</property>
                <property name="input_purpose">name</property>
                <signal name="activate" handler="on_text_name_activate" swapped="no"/>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="left_attach">1</property>
                <property name="top_attach">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkEntry" id="text_passwd">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="margin_right">47</property>
                <property name="visibility">False</property>
                <property name="invisible_char">*</property>
                <property name="input_purpose">password</property>
                <signal name="activate" handler="on_text_passwd_activate" swapped="no"/>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="left_attach">1</property>
                <property name="top_attach">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkEntry" id="text_numb">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="margin_right">47</property>
                <property name="input_purpose">phone</property>
                <signal name="activate" handler="on_text_numb_activate" swapped="no"/>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="left_attach">1</property>
                <property name="top_attach">2</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkLabel" id="nome">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Nome: </property>
                <property name="wrap">True</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="left_attach">0</property>
                <property name="top_attach">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkLabel" id="passwd">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Senha: </property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="left_attach">0</property>
                <property name="top_attach">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkLabel" id="numb">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Telefone: </property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="left_attach">0</property>
                <property name="top_attach">2</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButtonBox" id="buttonbox1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
            <property name="layout_style">start</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="submit">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Gravar</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                <property name="margin_top">30</property>
                <property name="margin_bottom">32</property>
                <signal name="clicked" handler="on_submit_clicked" swapped="no"/>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">True</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Eu deixo o campo nome em branco e ele me retorna o `print("n nula")`.

Comment: Tem algo errado? Me parece que está fazendo certo.

Comment: Então, eu tambem não estou entendendo por que isso está acontecendo. Eu deixo o campo nome em branco e ele me retorna o print("n nula")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Está funcionando certo. Você precisa decidir se quer saber se a variável é nula ou vazia, são conceitos completamente diferentes. O título pede uma coisa, o comentário pede outra.

Uma variável nula é como se não existe valor, o nada.

Uma variável ***string*** vazia tem um valor e seu valor é vazio, que é diferente de nada.

Pensa em uma caixa. Se ela não existe é nula, se ela existe e não tem coisas dentro ela é apenas vazia.

Então se quer saber se a variável é vazia, e isso só pode em tipos específicos como `string`, verifique assim:

```
if name == "":
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/String/IsEmpty.py)

Uma *string* é sempre delimitada no código por um par de aspas, portanto se ela estiver vazia só tem as aspas (que é a caixa de uma *string*) e nada dentro. O que o seu código fazia era verificar a nulidade e nunca era nula, era existente mas vazia. O `""` é como se fosse um 0 se fosse um número.

[image: Vazio X Nulo]

Comment: Era isso mesmo.

Answer (score 3):

Para verificar se a variável é nula, além das informações que foram passadas acima, você pode fazer assim também:

```
if name:
    [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Se for string pode fazer `if "string" == "":`
Para objetos pode se fazer `if objeto == None:`

Comment: Pode fazer "objeto is None" que é ainda mais explícito, pois o operador "is" é igualdade de identidade de objeto, enquanto  == pode ter alguma bruxaria pela implementação do operador \_\_eq\_\_

Comment: boa, nao sabia dessa.

Comment: Vlw pela dica..

Answer (score 0):

No python, para saber se uma variável está nula usamos is None

```
if name is None:
 // code
```